# LLVM GetAnalysis() failing with required passes

Tags: c++, llvm, flang

I have a custom set of passes created using LLVM to run on some bitcode.
I've managed to get it to compile, but whenever I try to run it with a pass that calls `getAnalysis()` on another pass type it fails with:

```
Assertion `ResultPass && "getAnalysis*() called on an analysis that was not " "'required' by pass!"' failed.
```

The custom pass that is calling `getAnalysis()` requires its type, specifically;

```
bool Operators::doInitialization(){
ParseConfig &parseConfig = getAnalysis<ParseConfig>(); // Fails here.
}
.
.
.
void Operators::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const{
    AU.addRequired<ParseConfig>();
    return;
}
```

I've spent a few days on this and am quite lost. I know the following is true:

- ParseConfig is registered successfully via the `RegisterPass<>` template, and I have stepped through it in GDB to find that it does get registered.
- Also using GDB I have found that when looking into `getAnalysis()` that the list of registered passes is always empty (which causes the assertion).

***Important Note***: I will eventually be using this on a Fortran project which is compiled with Flang, thus the LLVM library version I'm using is the Flang fork (found [here](https://github.com/flang-compiler/llvm)). That fork is right around LLVM 7.1, but the specific files associated with registering passes seems to not be different from the current LLVM library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `getAnalysis` function from `doInitialization` to `runOnFunction` would make it work.

---

From [LLVM page](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-analysisusage-addrequired-and-analysisusage-addrequiredtransitive-methods)

> This method call **getAnalysis*** returns a reference to the pass desired. You may get a runtime assertion failure if you attempt to get an analysis that you did not declare as required in your getAnalysisUsage implementation. This method can be called by your **run*** method implementation, or by any other local method invoked by your run* method.

Comment: I actually figured this out on my own just a few days ago. It turns out doInitialization is called by all other passes before any are run, so I was trying to get the analysis of a pass that had yet to be run. Thanks!